# Connecting Eclipse Ditto to Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, eclipse-hono, eclipse-ditto, eclipse-iot

I am following the instructions explained in this documentation to connect Apache Kafka to Eclipse Ditto.

https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/connectivity-protocol-bindings-kafka2.html

I am not sure about the following.

1) ["ditto:outbound-auth-subject", "..."] under the Authorization context.

2) "address": "topic/key"

Please let me know about them! Thank you in advance.!

**Edit:**

Please find the command that I used to connect Ditto and Kafka

```
curl -X POST -i -u devops:foobar -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
"targetActorSelection": "/system/sharding/connection",
"headers": {
    "aggregate": false
},
"piggybackCommand": {
    "type": "connectivity.commands:createConnection",
    "connection": {
        "id": "MyKafkaConnection1",
        "connectionType": "kafka",
        "connectionStatus": "open",
        "uri": "tcp://radsah:password@localhost:9092",
        "specificConfig": {
        "bootstrapServers": "10.196.2.218:9092",
        "saslMechanism": "plain"
        },
        "failoverEnabled": true,
        "targets": [
              {
             "address": "digital-twins",
              "topics": [
               "_/_/things/twin/events",
               "_/_/things/live/messages"
                            ],
            "authorizationContext": ["ditto:outbound-auth-subject"]
        }],
        "mappingContext": {
            "mappingEngine": "JavaScript",
            "options": {
                "incomingScript": "function mapToDittoProtocolMsg(\n    headers,\n    textPayload,\n    bytePayload,\n    contentType\n) {\n\n    if (contentType !== \"application/json\") {\n        return null;\n    }\n\n    var jsonData = JSON.parse(textPayload);\n    var temperature = jsonData.temp;\n    var humidity = jsonData.hum;\n    \n    var path;\n    var value;\n    if (temperature != null && humidity != null) {\n        path = \"/features\";\n        value = {\n                temperature: {\n                    properties: {\n                        value: temperature\n                    }\n                },\n                humidity: {\n                    properties: {\n                        value: humidity\n                    }\n                }\n            };\n    } else if (temperature != null) {\n        path = \"/features/temperature/properties/value\";\n        value = temperature;\n    } else if (humidity != null) {\n        path = \"/features/humidity/properties/value\";\n        value = humidity;\n    }\n    \n    if (!path || !value) {\n        return null;\n    }\n\n    return Ditto.buildDittoProtocolMsg(\n        \"org.eclipse.ditto\",\n        headers[\"device_id\"],\n        \"things\",\n        \"twin\",\n        \"commands\",\n        \"modify\",\n        path,\n        headers,\n        value\n    );\n}"
            }
        }
    }
}
}' http://localhost:8080/devops/piggyback/connectivity?timeout=8000
```

I have registered a device using Hono and I am sending the data to Ditto. Ditto successfully receives the data. But I want send this received data to Kafka.

Connection is successfully established between Kafka and Ditto. But I am not receiving at the kafka-consumer "digital-twins". Am I missing something?

**Edited with the Policy command:**

```
curl -X PUT 'http://localhost:8080/api/2/policies/org.eclipse.ditto:5100' -u 'ditto:ditto' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
"entries": {
    "owner": {
        "subjects": {
            "nginx:ditto": {
                "type": "nginx basic auth user"
            }
        },
        "resources": {
            "thing:/": {
                "grant": [
                    "READ","WRITE"
                ],
                "revoke": []
            },
            "policy:/": {
                "grant": [
                    "READ","WRITE"
                ],
                "revoke": []
            },
            "message:/": {
                "grant": [
                    "READ","WRITE"
                ],
                "revoke": []
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Is your problem solved or should we clarify anything in more detail?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got your point. But still confused in some ways. Do you know any articles that explains all the steps in detail for connection?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure what the problem is thats why I can't provide you any article. If its still the authorization context, then it's something specific to ditto. If its the address section then its specific to kafka connections and their topics.

Comment: Thank you again. Can you please check my edited question.

Comment: How does the policy of the Thing you're modifying look like?

I have a question regarding "I am ending the data to Ditto." Do you send the data via hono to ditto or directly to ditto?

Comment: And something unrelated to your question. You're exposing ditto publicly on http://srvgal90.deri.ie:8080. You should consider changing default passwords.

Comment: It is just some random data. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion. How can I change the default password?

Comment: @Yannic Klem ,Please check the edited question with the Policy.

Comment: Please have a look at my response again. The subject you define in the authorizationContext of the connection must be present in the policy of the thing.
In your case either add "nginx:ditto" as authorizationContext or add "ditto:outbound-auth-subject" as subject to the policy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

regarding the authorization context you can have a look at [the authorization section in our connections documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-connections.html#authorization). It has to hold a subject that is defined in the policy or ACL of your things.

As example:

The policy of Thing "foo:bar" has read access of the whole thing for subject "somePrefix:someValue" defined.

```
{
  "policyId": "foo:bar",
  "entries": {
    ... //Maybe more entries
    "MyKafkaConnection": {
      "subjects": {
        "somePrefix:someValue": {
          "type": "my description for this subject"
        }
      },
      "resources": {
        "thing:/": {
          "grant": [
            "READ"
          ],
          "revoke": []
        },
        "message:/": {
          "grant": [
            "READ"
          ],
          "revoke": []
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the sample you referring to, the events related to "foo:bar" would then be published via the kafka connection on the topic you specified in the address field.